# django models assigned via jquery ajax. 'unicode' object has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-models

I am having the following error with Django.

***'unicode' object has no attribute 'objects'***

I think the problem is in my **views.py**

I am passing the url via jquery ajax and it seems as it could not assing the url portion as an object of the models class.

The url is **domain.com/one/two/three**

The code in the **views.py**

```py
from lala.models import *

def function(request, one, two)
    foo = one.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM ...)
...
```

**one** is taken as no models object and I can not achieve to assign it.

The code in the **urls.py**

```
url(r'(?P<one>\bla\d{2})/(?P<two>[\w-]+)/three$', views., name='qwer'),
```

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A url is a string. The *one* and *two* arguments are substrings of your url (as described in your urls.py).

If you want your *one* argument to fetch a model name, you'll have to check it manually.

```
def function(request, one, two):
    if one == 'MyModel':
        MyModel.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM ...')
```